# Denormalized data error in importing excel to xml

Tags: xml, excel, testcase, testlink

want to convert excel sheet data into xml but getting following error 
how to resolve it

[image: excel to xml conversion error]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365320/export-denormalized-data-from-excel-to-xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export denormalized data from excel to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365320/export-denormalized-data-from-excel-to-xml)